# Php array_map remove empty arrays

Tags: php

I have a array:

```
$array = [
  0 => [],
  1 => ['name' => 'test']
  2 => ['name' => 'test 2']
];
```

I use function array_map for get name:

```
$names = array_map(function($item) {
      return $item['name'] ?? null;
}, $array);
```

I get "" in $names, how I can skip `[]` and get only names?

Answer (score 1):

Normally the quick and dirty answer would be to do an [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) after the `array_map` e.g.:

```
$names = array_filter(array_map(function($item) {
      return $item['name'] ?? null;
}, $array));
```

which is of course a long way of writing:

```
$names = array_column($array, 'name'));
```

See the manual for [details on `array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove empty array variables with `array_filter()`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php